# Web Service de Rastreamento Correios

Tags: java, c#, web-service

Li muitas vezes o [manual de utilização da web service de rastreamento do correios](https://www.correios.com.br/a-a-z/pdf/rastreamento-de-objetos/manual_rastreamentoobjetosws.pdf) e não consegui entender como consigo o usuário e senha para conseguir acessar. Estou a dias tentando entender e não consigo.

Comment: Se você pretende utilizar a API dos correios em seu sistema, entre em contato com uma das Agências para adquirir uma senha e username (Apesar de que você pode usar a API normalmente sem credenciais);

Comment: Como faço para utilizar sem credenciais? Lembrando que é para rastreamento, que até onde eu sei é obrigatório.

Comment: Pelas pesquisas vi que este serviço necessita das credenciais.

Comment: Já tentou: `usuário=ECT` e `senha=SRO` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Para ter acesso a este serviço, o cliente deverá:
>
> 1. Solicitar junto à área comercial da ECT a disponibilidade do serviço juntamente com o certificado de segurança emitido pela
>      autoridade responsável;
> 2. Receber, da área comercial, a autorização para execução do aplicativo, juntamente com uma identificação de usuário e senha de
>      conexão;
>
> Contato: sro@correios.com.br

[Fonte](https://www.correios.com.br/a-a-z/pdf/rastreamento-de-objetos/manual_rastreamentoobjetosws.pdf)